# NSAttributedString not working UITextVIew in IOS7

Tags: ios7, uitextview, uicolor, nsattributedstring

What is the reason, why this code is not working in IOS7? I am trying to set the color, but the color will not change, it keeps black:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *subString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"abc" attributes:attributes];

UITextView *textView = ....

textView.attributedText = subString;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this i am sure  it works because i have tested

```
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    NSAttributedString *subString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"abc" attributes:attributes];
```